# Conditionally disable buttons on continuous forms in Access

Tags: ms-access, continuous-forms

I have a continuous form in Access 2010 with a delete button that shows for each record shown on the form. I only want the delete button enabled on the very last record shown. I am stumped how to do it. Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why the last record? That sounds like an odd design decision.

Comment: So when you create a button on a continuous form it is the same button for every button you see. So if you enable/disable it for a record it is enabled/disabled for all records. Are you ok with using a text box and handling the click event on the textbox instead? I think that is a little more doable.

Answer (score 1):

In access there is only one instance of a component on any form - in continuous forms its just copied several times. The only way you can have anything different on any single row in a contiuous form is through data (obviously) and through conditional formatting of a data aware component: the textbox.
And the formatting options are also quite limited. So there are two options: EITHER use a textbox that has the same background as the form and create a conditional format that changes the backcolor for the last row OR create table (ID,PICTURE) with two rows - one with a transparent picture (ID=1) and one with the picture of a button (ID=2) - and link it in the recordsource (Somethig along the lines of: `SELECT .... pic FROM yourtable INNER JOIN pictable ON pictable.ID = yourtable.isLastRecord ...`